# Visual Studio 2022 comment shortcuts

Tags: c++, visual-studio, comments

Just starting out with C++ and was wondering if anyone can help - in Visual Studio 2022 I can add a comment with the shortcut ctrl+k, c or toggle with ctrl+/ however this just gives me line comments. Is there a shortcut for multi-line like this /* */ ?

I have had a look through the keymapping options but toggleblockcomment still gives me //. I would expect it to use /* unless I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: IMHO ctrl+k, c is a helpful shortcut for multi-line comments, you don't need a shortcut for /* ... */, because it's enough and easy to type in the first and the last lines

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try ctrl+shift+/, but don't use it for header files, if you do you will still get //.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply - this appears to do the same thing as ctrl+K, C. The shortcut either adds /* or // depending on what I have selected. Perhaps there is something I am not understanding about the way Visual Studio works?

Comment: @WillyBarno Hi, comments are mainly divided into block comments and line comments. I suggest you refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/comments-cpp?view=msvc-170) for details.